Topological Frobenius automorphism and prime gaps
The best upper bound for a prime gap occurring infinitely often obtained so far is $246=3^5+3^1$. Under Elliott-Halberstam conjecture, we can get $12=3^2+3$. This suggests a possible connection with finite fields, with extensions of prime order $q$  of $F_{p}$ and $p=3$ playing a key role in the structure of prime gaps. Geometrically, a prime gap is the Lebesgue measure, hence the "content", of a line segment which together with its extremities define $3$ compact sets.
Now define a "topological Frobenius automorphism" as follows:
Definition of a Topological Frobenius Automorphism
Let $X$ be a compact topological space, and let it be partitioned into finitely many compact subsets:
$X = \bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i, \quad X_i \text{ compact}, \quad X_i \cap X_j = \emptyset \, \text{for } i \neq j.$
A topological Frobenius automorphism $\phi$ on $X$ could be defined as a map:
$
\phi: X \to X
$
satisfying the following properties:

Preservation of the Partition:
$
   \phi(X_i) = X_{\sigma(i)}, \quad \sigma \text{ a permutation of } \{1, \dots, n\}.
   $
That is, $\phi$ permutes the compact subsets $X_i$ among themselves.

Homeomorphic Action on Each Subset:
For each $i$, $\phi|_{X_i}$ is a homeomorphism (continuous with a continuous inverse) from $X_i$ to $X_{\sigma(i)}$.

Iterative Consistency (Optional):
For a fixed number $p$, $\phi^p$ acts as the identity on $X$ (this is analogous to the behavior of the Frobenius automorphism in finite fields).



Intuition and Motivation

Analogy with Finite Fields:
In finite fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, the Frobenius automorphism $x \mapsto x^p$ cyclically permutes elements of certain algebraic structures, such as roots of polynomials. Similarly, a topological Frobenius automorphism permutes compact subsets within a compact topological space.

Partition as a Structure:
The partition into compact subsets acts as an algebraic or combinatorial structure, analogous to subspaces of vector spaces or subfields of field extensions.

Preservation of Geometric/Topological Features:
Such a map would preserve not just the topological space $X$ as a whole but also the finer partitioning structure, akin to how the Frobenius automorphism respects algebraic structure.


Properties of the Topological Frobenius Automorphism

Symmetry:
The map $\phi$ introduces symmetry by permuting compact subsets $ X_i$, much like symmetries in Galois theory or algebraic topology.

Cyclic Behavior:
If $\sigma$ (the permutation induced by $\phi$ is a cyclic permutation, $\phi$ generates a cyclic group of order $n$, analogous to the Frobenius automorphism generating a cyclic Galois group.

Invariant Subsets:
Fixed points or invariant subsets under $\phi$ correspond to subsets $X_i $ that map onto themselves.

Algebraic/Topological Interplay:
If $X$ has additional algebraic or combinatorial structure (e.g., a simplicial complex or CW complex), $\phi$ could be defined to preserve these structures as well.


That way the topological Frobenius automorphism mimicks the usual algebraic Frobenius automorphism in finite fields theory.
The primeness of the order of extension $q$ implies the only subfields thereof are it self and the prime field $F_3$. This resonates with the number of primes in $[p_{n},p_{n+1}]$.
That way, we may expect as a further improvement of Polymath8b result to get a refined upper bound of $30=3^3+3$, which, incidentally, appears to also be a jumping champion and thus a good a priori candidate for this role.
My question is thus: can one hope to reach such a bound in a not too distant future? Which level of distribution of primes would be needed?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliott%E2%80%93Halberstam_conjecture says, "In August 2014, Polymath group showed that subject to the generalized Elliott–Halberstam conjecture, one can show the existence of infinitely many pairs of consecutive primes that differ by at most 6." Continuing the numerology of this post, we note that $6=3^2-3$.

This "numerology" may be backed up by some heuristics as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681590/difference-of-prime-powers-as-linear-combination-of-jumping-champions
